# How to translate module title in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, translate

I'm using Joomla version 3.5.1

I'm using language switcher, currently my site has 2 languages installed. Translation works on everything, except for module title. How do I make the site automatically switch to appropriate language automatically without having to hardcode?

I see proper translation already done for the title of this module=> `admnistrator/language/ta-IN/ta-IN.mod_popular.sys.ini`

But wonder why it doesn't appear? Do I need to enable it or something?

Answer (score 0):

For your joomla frontend translation the language files should be in /language folder not in /administrator/language folder. You also have to look at these facts given in this urls 1.

1. https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files
2. https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_language_definition_file

If you want automatic switch over to another language you can do it through country IP. As the IP changes the language file changes. Have a look at  this link http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=884661

Also please check that in Module settings you have chosen to display Module name.
[image]
Check the Show Title on the right.

Comment: it is in front end too..and all content translated corrrectly, just the module title

Comment: Have you checked that it is unique name and is not repeated anywhere?

Comment: yeah, moreover its joomla's sample modules

Comment: @Keren check module settings where you option to display/hide module title. I think it is set hidden.